# SQL Server Prod Backup won't restore to dev machine

Tags: backup, ssms

I looked at the files needed for the db to operate, and changed their paths to the dev's file system.

But dev server will not restore the backup file?

Do I need to get Master as well as MSDB, or is this a difference between versions of SSMS Enterprise SP1 and Developer SP2.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or want) copies of master and msdb from the prod machine.  It's not a difference between enterprise and developer, they're binary equivalents (just a different licensing scheme).

If your dev server is a lower version of SQL Server than your production server then you won't be able to restore to it from backups of the production server databases (even if the database compatibility level is set to the lower version).

Might also be a permissions thing on the dev server.

You might also have a corrupt backup file...

Comment: Could be wrong drive letter. The solution escapes me at the moment, but we do this all the time.

Comment: I have done this before numerous times.  :)

This time it is just not flowing through.

Comment: Ok, I'm with you.  Like AdamB said in the comment to your question, what error(s) are you getting?  A lot can kill a restore...